# Image Cut off using Background: Cover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a background image to show the top part of the image under my current navigation. However I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong here.

HTML:

```
<section class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.<br><br>.
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url("../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat bottom #b1b0b6;
    padding: 10% 2%; 
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

With these current settings it shows this:

[image]

But the full image is this:
[image]

My live preview of it is here:

http://podpanel.pw/

I've exhausted all options. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: All css is fixable, it is a matter of knowing what the goal is. I am confused as to whether you want the nav bar moved down the image or hidden under the image until the is a 'mouseover' event. How far down the image do you want the nav bar to be?

Comment: @Sparky256 I want this image under the navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the `top part` of the image `under navigation`, Try adding this CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
    background-position-y: 0;
}
```

***background-position-y*** property will sets the starting position of a background image on y-axis, *I hope it helps you, Thanks.*